# How to show time along with date using Angular Material Date Picker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have added angular material date picker control in my angular project. I have to show the time along with the date. 
Can anyone let me know how can I show time along with the date using angular material date picker control?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can build a custom component using the DateTime Component of the Angular MateriaL.

```
<h1 class="mat-title">Angular Material DatetimePicker</h1>
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-placeholder>Start DateTime</mat-placeholder>
        <input matInput formControlName="startDate" [matDatetimepicker]="dts" required autocomplete="false">
        <mat-datetimepicker-toggle [for]="dts" matSuffix></mat-datetimepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datetimepicker #dts type="datetime" openOnFocus="true" timeInterval="5"></mat-datetimepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datetimepicker-issue-mutexm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: how can I set digital time in the code you mentioned? Right now, it's showing analog time.

Comment: The time control in your example is showing analog time. A clock or watch is called "analog" when it has moving hands and (usually) hours marked from 1 to 12 to show you the time.

Comment: Its a matter of customimizing

Comment: Can you please guide me on how can I customize digital time in place of analog?

Comment: well you need to create custom input boxes for time , currently only analog way is supported https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5648

Comment: This is not the Angular Material way of doing it.